# Specifying h5py path when writing a file?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

The documentation states that to write an HDF5 file:

```
>>> f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5','w')
```

But I am having trouble finding any resources in the documentation or elsewhere about how to specify *where* this file should be. Can I just give `File()` a full path?

```
>>> f = h5py.File('path/to/file/myfile.hdf5','w')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can. Just completely write down the path from `/` or `~`, like this: `/Users/Mathias/Desktop/myfile.hdf5' (if you are on a Mac, your username is Mathias, and the file should be on the desktop).